# Unchecking a CheckBox from a Style Setter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have multiple datatriggers of the form:

```
 <Style x:Key="VerifyCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=PrimaryInsuranceCompany, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
```

The  `IsEnabled` property on the *CheckBox* is set correctly. However, the `IsChecked` property does not get unchecked if it had been manually checked in the first place.

Can `IsChecked` be unchecked from a Setter?

Edit#1

```
To complicate matters a bit more, the checkbox is bound to a property in my viewmodel as:

  <CheckBox 
                  Style="{StaticResource VerifyCheckBox}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.SelectedInsurance.Verify}" 
                  Content="Verify" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="789,92,0,676" Width="46" />
```

And there are multiple DataTrigger s in the Style.Triggers each checking a different element on the UI. In short, the UI has all the data validation. For instance, the element named above, PrimaryInsuranceCompany is:

```
 <wc:AutoFilteredComboBox 
                  Name="PrimaryInsuranceCompany"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.Enabled}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.AllCompanies}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CompanyTemplate}"
                  IsEditable="True"
                  IsCaseSensitive="False" 
                  IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
                  TextSearch.TextPath="Companyname"
                  Text="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.NewCompanyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  theFilter="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.TheFilter}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.SelectedInsurance.Company}"
                  h:ComboBoxRegexValidator.RegexText="{x:Static h:RegexLibrary.NonEmptyRegex}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="590,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="363"  />
```

So with the combobox element in particular, I was trying to avoid duplicating the validation process in the view model since it is already being done directly in the view. Can this be done?

Comment: The IsChecked property is certainly bound to some view model property.

Comment: @Clemens Yes...It is. Please see my above edit. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This quite often causes a confusion. You might want to read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.
Basically, dependency properties in wpf might be set in different places: locally (IsChecked=True), in style, in trigger, and so on. When property is set in multiple places, specific resolution order is used to resolve the conflict. Here is an example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="VerifyCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestValue}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />                    
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<CheckBox Content="Hey there" IsChecked="True" Style="{StaticResource VerifyCheckBox}" />
```

Here we set IsChecked in *two* places: locally (IsChecked=True) and in trigger. Local value has higher priority and because of that, when TestValue will become true checkbox will *not* be unchecked. However we did not set IsEnabled locally, so it will have it's value from trigger. Note that if we *did* set IsEnabled=True locally, trigger would have no effect at all.

Now let's try like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="VerifyCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestValue}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />                    
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<CheckBox Content="Hey there" Style="{StaticResource VerifyCheckBox}" />
```

We moved IsChecked initial setter in style and now it works as expected, because trigger has priority over values in style setter.

Update: user clicking does not change behavior above. So, if you have local IsChecked=True, then user clicked twice, then TestValue becomes true - it will not be unchecked. And if you do the same but initialize IsChecked=True in style setter - it will be unchecked.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... And what if the user clicks the `CheckBox` and hence the `IsChecked` property changes? Does that also override the values on the Style or Triggers? Or it doesn't affect them?

Comment: Updated with answer to your comment.

Comment: @Evk And what happens if the CheckBox IsChecked dp is bound to a property on the viewmodel which initializes it?  Great answer btw. Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne well you can check yourself :) Binding will take over, so trigger again won't work. But in this case it's logical - otherwise trigger will break your binding (if it is one-way).

Comment: @Evk Please see my edit.  How is this done with binding without duplicating the validation code? Or do I need to do both? Thanks.

Comment: Validating using style triggers is not the best idea. Validation is operation on data, and your data is in viewmodel. In your case I'd remove "validation" trigger and bind IsEnabled of CheckBox to some property like CanVerify on your model. And in model, when CanVerify goes to false, set Verify flag to false too. This way your UI just represent state of your viewmodel, and no problem with triggers.

Comment: @Evk Thanks.  Oh well,  I was trying to avoid all the extra code :(